# Is it possible to ruduce background network use when on mobile wifi hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, bandwidth, background-process

Short version: What is the easiest way to temporarily reduce the amount of background network traffic to a minimum?

Long Version: I'm connecting to a mobile wi-fi hotspot hosted by my cell phone, If ubuntu decides to run software update or apt-get update/upgrade that could easily use up my entire monthly data in one go, at which point I start running up big bills.

Extra Credit:
If these settings can be saved/remembered against the wifi network, so that whenever I connect to the mobile hotspot data use is minimised, and then when I connect to my office or home wi-fi again, the floodgates can be opened.

Duplicates: I have searched, but haven't found anything I'm happy to be redirected

Edit: I'm on 14:04 LTS - but if anything is available in later versions I'd still like to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off automatic updates and checks for automatic updates by:

Open Software & Updates and on the Updates tab change `Automatically check for updates` to `Never`.

Also, disable any automatic backup services such as Google Drive, Ubuntu One, Dropbox, etc,.